# ASP.NET Web API loading controller inconsistently

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a RESTful web server application using the ASP.NET Web API framework. It has a few different controllers servicing requests, but I'm having trouble with one of the controllers being loaded inconsistently on different machines. The controller loads correctly on two developer machines and one of our QA machines, but doesn't load on one developer machine and one other QA machine. The other controllers load correctly on all machines, so we know the application works on at least some level. What makes matters more confusing is that the name of the controller class changes whether it loads correctly or not. The original design called for the class to be named like "XyzController", which follows the required naming format as far as I can tell. If I change the name of the controller to anything else, like "MyXyzController" or "XyzV2Controller", it gets loaded correctly. Of course we could just rename the controller, but we'd really like to find the root cause of this issue so we aren't stuck wondering which machines which names will work on.

I have to believe that it's a configuration/setup issue between the machines that it's working on and the machines it's not, but I can't imagine what configuration would impact the framework's ability to load "MyXyzController" but not "XyzController". There seems to be no consistency between the OS, IIS, and .NET versions where it works or not.

I specify routes entirely using RoutePrefixAttributes and RouteAttributes, not allowing the framework to decide the routes, so I'm not worried about collisions between the routes or class names.

Comment: Have you tried to clean the project folder in the "Temporary ASP.NET Files"? Recycling the IIS pool could also help.

Comment: Sounds like IIS/Server has an old deployment too on the machines its not behaving properly. Clean the project and remove the old versions from IIS then try again XyzController would work.

Comment: Yep, I've tried cycling the app pool and removing all binaries from the IIS deployment folder and redeploying. The VisualStudio project gets cleaned and rebuilt regularly too. After deploying MyXyzController, if I switch back to XyzController, it goes back to not working.

Comment: Unless we can see some code and reproduce the issue its hard to help. But this is machine based rather than code based. Have you turn on verbose logs on? Maybe it might shed some light.

Comment: I don't see any different log level settings in IIS, so I'm not sure how verbose they are, but the log file I do have indicates that all requests to this controller are returning 404 (which I knew) and have an sc-win32-status of 2, which corresponds to ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. I have a hard time believing that because just changing the class name allows it to magically find the file.